# How can I not order more than one bucket of popcorn (if statement)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, set

Why can I type popcorn 2 or more times in a row

without giving me an error since I used set.add and second time when I type popcorn should give me an error since I can't have two same values in a set ? How can I do it so I can type only one time popcorn and give me an error second time when I try to type popcorn.

````
public void Popcorn() {
        boolean stop = false;
        while (!stop) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            if (s.equals("popcorn")&&!set.contains("popcorn")) {
                set.add("popcorn");
                int popcorn = 5;
                setPopCornValue(getPopCornValue() + popcorn);
                continue;
                }
     
            }
            if(s.equals("exit")){
                stop=true;
                break;
            }

    } ```
````

Comment: Because of the if statement. When you type `popcorn` a second time, the statement in the if clause is false (because of `!set.contains("popcorn")`), therefore nothing happens.

Comment: Btw `Set.add` will return `false`, if the element is already in the `Set`. It won't throw an exception, which you may think as `give me an error`. 
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-)

Comment: ohh that's why , I was really confused

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Javadoc for HashSet.add(E) you will see that is defined as

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
> More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set
> contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
> unchanged and returns false.

Thus, you can do something like

```
 if (set.add(s)) {
   .. do stuff for having added popcorn
 } else {
   .. do stuff for having rejected popcorn because we already have it
 }
```